# Kubernetes Issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have a Micro service (on Node.js)
I am creating a docker image for it and pushing it to my local registry running at
localhost:5001

While deploying this micro service using helm

```
helm upgrade --install --wait --set env=dev --set image.tag=localhost:5001/user-service userservice-api ./build/helm --namespace dev --create-namespace --kube-context http://localhost:5001
```

I get

> Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: context "http://localhost:5001"
> does not exist

How do i find out the issue/resolve it?

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "chart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "chart.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "chart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "chart.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}    
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 4006
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ENV
              value: "{{ .Values.env }}"
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 4006
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 10

          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 4006
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 10
```

values.yaml

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: localhost:5001/user-service
```

Additional Information
[image: Pods]

Can someone please help me with the issue?

Comment: `--kube-context http://localhost:5001` the value shoud be a **k8s cluster context**, not your helm registry.

Comment: It is K8s context Lei as i can see.
Can you help me understand it further, I am novice with K8s.

Comment: can you paste the working `kubectl` command to get the pods?

Comment: > kubectl get pods
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "pods"

Comment: get svc instead?

Comment: > kubectl get svc
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "svc"

Comment: if you have trouble using `kubectl`, `helm` won't work either. fix `kubectl` first.

Comment: `helm --kube-context` specifies the name of a `context:` block in the `$HOME/.kube/config` file, and matches `kubectl config get-contexts`.  I'm not used to seeing that as a URL.

Comment: Hello @RohitMittal, any updates?

Comment: is not fixed. 
I am trying to figure it out

Comment: please edit your title. It doesnt help anyone doing a websearch for similar problems in the future. It does also not express something new since your question is already tagged with kubernetes.

Comment: Could you add more details? Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? Also, please, attach the output of `kubectl config current-context`, and, if possible, share your kubeconfig, with sensitive data obfuscated

Comment: ➜  ~ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.0", GitCommit:"ab69524f795c42094a6630298ff53f3c3ebab7f4", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-07T18:08:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/arm64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.3", GitCommit:"c92036820499fedefec0f847e2054d824aea6cd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T18:35:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm64"}
➜  ~ kubectl config current-context gives Minikube
minikube

Comment: I create a docker image named user-service, push it to local registry, tagged it to localhost:5001/user-service pushed it to local repository and now i am trying to create deploy it using helm/minikube

➜  userservice git:(feature/adding-liveliness-probes) ✗ helm upgrade --install --wait --set env=dev  --set image.tag=1 userservice-api ./build/helm  --namespace  default
Release "userservice-api" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: timed out waiting for the condition

Comment: Are you able to deploy pods using images from your local registry? You have `ImagePullBackOff` status for pods on your screenshot. Have you fixed the reason?

Comment: Thank you team.
Issue is resolved and answer had been posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Dockerfile

```
RUN npm ci
```

had to be changed to

In Dockerfile

```
RUN npm ci --force
```

resolved issue for me.